# How to turn API response into an image?

Tags: php, api, curl, postman

I'm trying to work with an API using Postman. In Postman the image displays fine. I am using Postman to generate the following code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.com/v2/tier1/XXXXX/photos/photo/MYPHOTOIDISHERE/download?api_key=MYAPIKEYISHERE",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "postman-token: 74f19da6-d4ba-fe02-4ad3-2a313b472ca2"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

The only modification I have made to the code from Postman is the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` as I was getting an error.

The image displays perfectly in Postman but when I try to use the code myself I get a long string that looks like UTF. A small sample (it's very long) of this is as follows;

``` ����JFIF``��C  #!!!$'$ & ! ��C  ����"��    ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4� ```

How do I convert this into an image?

Comment: What do mean by 'turn it into an image'?  Is the JPEG corrupt?  It's hard to tell from your output - perhaps you should show a hexdump rather than lines full of replacement character(`�`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are seeing is the actual bytes of the image.

You need to save that to a file or process it as image bytes. To save it, dump it to a file using [file_put_contents($filename, $data)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
// Instead of 'echo $response';
file_put_contents('image.jpg', $response);
```

You will see a new file `image.jpg` in your script's directory.

This assumes the image is a jpeg, you could do some checks to determine the type before saving it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks Donovan.

Clint

Answer (score -1):

I am able to save image in folder, but problem is that Its showing error - window photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or is too large

here is my code

```
$oAuthToken = $token->access_token;
        $getUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' . $googlefileid . '?alt=media';
        $authHeader = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $oAuthToken ;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            $authHeader ,
        ]);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        Storage::put($googlfilename,$data);
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Answers are not the place to ask for help. You should open a new question instead.